# File saved using ContentVersion appears distorted or low quality

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, files, contentversion, encodingutil

Using this link - [Convert event.target.files into a JSON string](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/302170/convert-event-target-files-into-a-json-string) I was able to get the file data. I form a JSON with like - `{'fileName':xyz.jpeg,'file': <fileContent>}` and pass it to an Apex Controller. I used below code to insert the file ( using ContentVersion metadata ) like below (https://www.salesforcecodecrack.com/2019/06/custom-file-upload-in-lightning-web.html)

```
    String fileData = EncodingUtil.urlDecode((String)data.get('file'), 'UTF-8');
    // inserting file
    ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
    cv.Title = (String)data.get('fileName');
    cv.PathOnClient = '/' + data.get('fileName');
    cv.FirstPublishLocationId = '0033h0000054rJVAAY'; // A contact record Id to test
    cv.VersionData = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(fileData);
    cv.IsMajorVersion = true;
    insert cv;
```

contentVersion is inserted successfully and I was able to download the image. However the image is not clear and look like it has been distorted. How do I store the original version of the file.

[image]

Comment: have you considered using a multipart upload? it appears to me like the file may have only partially when in

Comment: How could i confirm if the file have only partially when in. May be i could debug based on that?

Comment: what is the size of the file listed on the ContentDocument in the ContentSize field and how does it compare to the actual file you dropped in?

Comment: original file is 8 KB and in the debug logs I see (9273946)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[19]|this.VersionData|BLOB(8268 bytes)|0x4150d8d

Comment: what does it show on the record? not the log. SELECT Id, ContentSize FROM ContentDocument WHERE Id = '<your Id>'

Comment: it shows 8268 in ContentSize

Comment: `window.Base64.encode(<the file here>)` Try adding this into your LWC upload function to ensure that it is base64 encoded, and you are not base64 decoding something that is not encoded on the other end.

Comment: you may also need to work with this npm  by including it as a resource `npm install --save js-base64` https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-base64

Comment: Thanks. I had to not use this - EncodingUtil.urlDecode((String)data.get('file'), 'UTF-8'); instead just get (String)data.get('file') and decode it and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
`EncodingUtil.urlDecode((String)data.get('file'), 'UTF-8')`
```

wasn't necessary. decoding just this `(String)data.get('file')` was the right way.

Comment: just remember, if you're not encoding, you should never have to decode it (assuming you're controlling the content and it is not downloaded as base64)

Comment: Got it. Actually its result of File ReaderAsDataURL which always return base64encoded string

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL Maybe that `Note` attached here may be part of it.